# Count number of lines in terminal and save those lines to a text files and save the number to variable

Tags: bash

I have a shell script (let's say test.sh) which prints out 16 values on screen and sometimes error messages on screen (because of upstream hardware issues). I want to count the number of lines on the screen and then save only when I have valid outputs. I am unable to do the both at same time.

I am new to the shell scripting , so I did something pretty basic

```
./test.sh | tee -a output1.txt       
A=./test.sh | wc -l
```

When I do this it doesn't save the length in A

```
./test.sh | tee -a output1.txt       
A=./test.sh | wc -l
```

Comment: What have you tried? For example, have you checked the output of `echo "$A"`?

Comment: shouldn't you have an if-statement somewhere that checks the number of lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do both at the same time. But you can do them one at a time.

I think you want to check whether `./test.sh` prints 16 lines, and if so, save its output to a file. This does that:

```
output=$(./test.sh)  # Capture output from "./test.sh" as "$output"
line_count=$(wc -l <<< "$output")  # Count lines in "$output"

if (( line_count = 16 )); then  # Check if "$line_count" is 16
    tee -a output1.txt <<< "$output"  # Append "$output" to "output1.txt" and stdout
fi
```

Notes

- `cmd <<< str` does the same thing as `echo str | cmd`.
- `(( line_count = 16 ))` does the same thing as `[[ $line_count -eq 16 ]]`

Comment: Thanks Wjandrea  and sorry for my late reply as I was on training.

Comment: It worked. I am still trying to learn the bash commands and its pretty cool to learn all these. thanks again